# Makefile for creating C++ shared library with cuda functions

Tags: c++, c, cuda, makefile

EDITED:(I dont have error in compile time but using share library come to error or warning)

I have a function that I have ported from cpu to GPU. I have defined my cuda functions in port.cu and  the functions that call the gpu kernel is invoked from CNVEncoderH264.cpp.

I want to link these two file to gather in order to create an shared library to use in another program , this is my make file:

```
    port.o: port.cu
        nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -dc -Xcompiler '-fPIC' port.cu -c -o port.o
        nvcc port.cu -c -o cudafile.o
main.o: main.cpp ../core/include/nvFileIO.h
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

ffmpeg_interface.o: ffmpeg_interface.c ../core/include/nvFileIO.h
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<


NvPthreadABI.o: ../core/threads/NvPthreadABI.cpp
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

NvThreadingClasses.o: ../core/threads/NvThreadingClasses.cpp
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

NvThreadingLinux.o: ../core/threads/NvThreadingLinux.cpp
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

utilities.o: src/utilities.cpp
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

xcodeutil.o: src/xcodeutil.cpp inc/xcodeutil.h
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

CNVEncoderH264.o: src/CNVEncoderH264.cpp utilities.o ffmpeg_interface.o inc/CNVEncoder.h
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<


CNVEncoder.o: src/CNVEncoder.cpp inc/CNVEncoder.h
        $(GCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

libnvenc.so:  port.o NvPthreadABI.o NvThreadingClasses.o NvThreadingLinux.o xcodeutil.o CNVEncoder.o CNVEncoderH264.o utilities.o ffmpeg_interface.o
        gcc  -shared  -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@  port.o  NvPthreadABI.o NvThreadingClasses.o NvThreadingLinux.o xcodeutil.o CNVEncoder.o CNVEncoderH264.o utilities.o ffmpeg_interface.o -lstdc++  -lnvidia-encode -lcuda -lcudart $(LDFLAGS) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS)
```

this is my output of make command :

```
    nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -dc -Xcompiler '-fPIC' port.cu -c -o port.o
nvcc port.cu -c -o cudafile.o
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o NvPthreadABI.o -c ../core/threads/NvPthreadABI.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o NvThreadingClasses.o -c ../core/threads/NvThreadingClasses.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o NvThreadingLinux.o -c ../core/threads/NvThreadingLinux.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o xcodeutil.o -c src/xcodeutil.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o CNVEncoder.o -c src/CNVEncoder.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o utilities.o -c src/utilities.cpp
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o ffmpeg_interface.o -c ffmpeg_interface.c
g++ -m64 -O0 -ggdb3 -fPIC -fopenmp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I./include -I../inc -I../core -I../core/include -I./inc -I . -o CNVEncoderH264.o -c src/CNVEncoderH264.cpp
gcc  -shared  -Wl,-soname,libnvenc.so -o libnvenc.so  port.o  NvPthreadABI.o NvThreadingClasses.o NvThreadingLinux.o xcodeutil.o CNVEncoder.o CNVEncoderH264.o utilities.o ffmpeg_interface.o -lstdc++  -lnvidia-encode -lcuda -lcudart -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -L/usr/lib64 -lnvidia-encode -ldl
```

when I use this shared library in my program I get this error :

```
 symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libnvenc.so: undefined symbol: __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0000257a_00000000_6_port_cpp1_ii_58a1dcc4
```

it seems , I couldn't link them properly , what's wrong ?

Edit :
the command when use shared library before

```
enabled libnvenc    && require  libnvenc x264.h x264_encoder_encode -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnvenc  &&
                      { check_cpp_condition x264.h "X264_BUILD >= 118" ||
                        die "ERROR: libnvenc version must be >= 0.118."; }
```

after my friends suggestion I add -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart after the -lnvenc.

Comment: What is your compile command when you want to use the shared library?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile c and c++ files.

by default c++ is loking for c++ function signature, therefor it can't find the c function.

you need to declare the prototype as a c protoype

try something like this from the c++ file:

```
extern "C" {
#include "header.h" //header contain c prototypes
}
```

you can try also put only the prototype for the functions you are calling:

In the file.cpp: (instead of the include)

```
 extern "C" {
        //lets asume this is the prototype
        void convert(int x, char y);
 }
```

**EDIT:**

you are missing share flags for link:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so.0 *.o
```

and after this:

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /path/to/so
```

(without the file in the path)

OR if you have root privilege:

```
 /sbin/ldconfig  /path/to/so
```

(again, without the file in the path)

Comment: I did like this but , when I use the shared library in my program  the error changed to like this :           symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libnvenc.so: undefined symbol: convertYUVpitchtoNV12